# Exception while Parsing Hexadecimal to Short in Java

Tags: java, java.util.scanner

In file data.hex, the data is given in hexadecimal form where the first digit of hexadecimal number is always less than 8. Eg.

```
01FC 04BF 04C0 04C1 04C2 24C3 04C4 34C5 ...
```

To parse this file and store the values in shrt[] array i have written this code

```
void read_hex_short(String filename, short[] shrt, int x, int y) throws Exception
{
    String str;
    Scanner s=new Scanner(new BufferedReader(new FileReader(filename)));
    for(int i=0;i<height*width;i++)
    {
        str= s.next();    // i have tried str="0x"+s.next() but it didn't work
        image[i]=(short)Integer.parseInt(str);
    }
    s.close();
}
```

But i am getting NumberFormatException  which arises while passing the first string i.e. 01FC only. 
How can i parse these hexadecimal values and store them in the shrt[] array?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You should be using `Integer.parseInt(str, 16)` to tell it to use hex.

You should also be aware that any values greater than 0x7FFF will end up being negative in your array: Java doesn't have any unsigned numeric types (unless you count `char`).

Answer (score 5):

You can use [`Short.parseShort(str, 16)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/lang/Short.html#parseShort%28java.lang.String,%20int%29) to parse HEX. This will avoid the need to cast it to `short` from an `int`.

Answer (score 2):

Give parseInt method a radix parameter. Like this:

```
Integer.parseInt(str, 16)
```